# AngularJS Partial Directive Dropdown Not Working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am adding a dropdown to a sidebar that I am loading as a directive partial template.  All the css is loading fine from my base.html but the dropdown is not working in my sidebar.html.  If I cut and paste the html from sidebar.html into base.html, the dropdown is working fine.  All other css appears to be working.  Everything but the tree seems to be ok in the partial.   Thanks.

Base.html

```
    <aside class="left-side sidebar-offcanvas">      
     <side-bar></side-bar>
    </aside >
```

Sidebar.html

```
 <div class="sidebar">

        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                    <span>Group Name</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="/members/"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Members</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Calender</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Albums</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('App')
  .directive('sideBar', function(appService) {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        replace:'true',

      templateUrl: '/static/templates/sidebar.html'

}
});
```

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? Are you aware of the fact that the 'replace' attribute is not supported anymore with Angular 1.3.x?

Comment: Currently using 1.26.  I didn't know that about replace good to know.